# Fragment Resetting and losing data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I am working on an Android app that needs to be connectedto some hardware and provide real time data to the end user through a  linear chart. For that I am using MPAndroid library to show this Linear Chart inside a fragment.
This is what it look like [image: Linear Chart]

My problem is when I go to another view and comeback to my chart fragment, the chart lose all its value and goes back to the initial state. I tried putting my chart inisialization in OnCreate then in OnAttach, but it didn't work. My chart needs to keep those values until the end of the hour yet moving from screen to screen reset everything.
This is my code:

```
        c=Calendar.getInstance();
        minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        setXAxisValues( String.valueOf(hour));
        setYAxisValues();
```

this code need to be called only when I enter the fragment for the first time and never be called again cauz it just set the chart.

**EDIT**

This is my code accordding to Piyush suggestion:

```
    if (savedInstanceState!= null) {
        yVals=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("savedList");
        Log.e("TAG","********************************************saved instance*********************************************");
    }
    else {
        c=Calendar.getInstance();
        minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        setXAxisValues( String.valueOf(hour));
        Log.e("TAG","********************************************not saved*********************************************");
        yVals=setYAxisValues();
    }
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_acceuil, container, false);
```

Comment: While working with fragment you have to take care of some points whenever fragment get killed it will remove all the data, and if you go back to that fragment you wont get the data again.To store the data you can use DataModel for temporary storage or SharedPreference or SQlite or MYSql for storage.

Comment: You are working with fragment so my opinion to over come with is to store data in `onSavedInstance()` method and get data in `onCreateView()` with check if bundle is null or not. If not null then set your data which will give you your old data without lose it. Also set `setRetainInstance(true)` in `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: I tried it, still am not getting back my data.

Comment: @MeknessiHamida What you mean by 'go to another view' ? Is it new activity ? or new fragment in the same activity?

Comment: in both cases I need the data to be kept.

Comment: @MeknessiHamida How did u use it ? Show it

Comment: @MeknessiHamida post some more code

Comment: Check my edit please, that's where I am saving my List of Entries

Comment: You should check `if(savedInstanceState!=null) {yVals=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("savedList");}`

Comment: I checked like you suggested, It dosen't enter the `if(savedInstanceState!=null)` block, its always entering the `else`

Comment: @MeknessiHamida maybe you are creating new instance of fragment . >Please check that oo

Comment: @Krish how to check that please and where ?

Comment: @MeknessiHamida How did you adding this fragment?

Comment: this is how am addind the fragment ` case 0:

                AcceuilFragment acceuilFragment = new AcceuilFragment();
                return acceuilFragment;` I guess its creating the fragment each time

Comment: @MeknessiHamida Where did you calling this method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143295/discussion-between-krish-and-meknessihamida).

Comment: @MeknessiHamida Did you solve the issue?

Comment: No I am still working on it, my current approach is saving my ArrayList in the MainActivity (that launches my fragments) and send it to my fragment but now am in an infinte loop.

Comment: @Krish I solved my problem, please refer to this [Sending data to the container activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802535/sending-data-to-the-container-activity)

Answer (score 0):

onResume is Called when the activity will start interacting with the user.

So You'd better call again!

```
  @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            c=Calendar.getInstance();
            minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            setXAxisValues( String.valueOf(hour));
            setYAxisValues();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener in MainActivity then in that call onResume method like this way

```
   @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fr = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
        if (fr != null) {
            fr.onResume();
        }
    }
```

then in each fragment's onResume method you have reload updated data again